# Documentation sources for Scala cross referencing in traits

Tags: scala, design-patterns, traits

Sometime ago I saw such example of defining traits that allow the extender to choose what implementation is easier and override one of the methods:

```scala
trait Foo {
  def eq(x: Any): Boolean = !neq(x)
  def neq(x: Any): Boolean = !eq(x)
}

final class Bar extends Foo {
  override def eq(x: Any): Boolean = x.toString == "bar"
}
```

So here there is no **full** (in terms of non-looping, computationally final) implementation of the *Foo*, but once one of the methods *eq* or *neq* is implemented, then the implementation is **full**.

I made the example specific to `eq` and `neq` but it can be generalised to any interface, where implementation of one attributes can be evaluated on another attributes.

I can't find that doc now, so asking if anybody have it at hand.

Comment: I thought it was in Scala with Cats book, or in example of extending an Ordering trait... but not

Comment: To be fair, also the first implementation is *full*, the problem here is that it makes an infinite recursive call. Perhaps are you interested in [stackable](https://www.artima.com/articles/scalas-stackable-trait-pattern) trait?

Comment: No, that doc, where I saw that was putting an accent on exact such implementation which is _looping_. Just can't find that doc now (as usual) :)